# Copy csv to PostgreSQL table using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I am trying to copy csv file to PostgreSQL table with Python. I've created the empty table in PostgreSQL DB, I just need to copy the data, which have no headers, from the csv file into the PostgreSQL table by using Python script.
I've tried two methods, on both I get no error but the PostgreSQL table remains empty.
Please help.
1.

```
import psycopg2

csv = df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)  
csv = open('file.csv', 'r')         
conn_string = "host='abcd.com' dbname='AB_DB' user='AQWS'   password='zxcvbn'"  
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)   
cursor = conn.cursor()  
cursor.copy_from(csv, 'schema.postgres_table', sep = ',')  
csv.close()
```

2.

```
conn_string = "host='abcd.com' dbname='AB_DB' user='AQWS' password='zxcvbn'"  
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)  
cursor = conn.cursor()  
sqlstr = "COPY schema.postgres_table FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV"  
with open('file.csv') as f:                                                                                                                                                                             
    cursor.copy_expert(sqlstr, f)     

conn.close()
```

Comment: Try using cursor.copy_from instead of the sqlstr.  This post has an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559300/copy-command-with-psycopg2-library

Comment: Hi Joe, appreciate your quick response. As you can see in my code I've already tried it and as  mentioned the code is executed but the PostgreSQL table remains empty.

Comment: Did you try to `conn.commit()` before `conn.close()`?

Comment: Hi Clodoaldo, I've also tried conn.commit() before conn.close() but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Apparently conn.commit() did the trick, thanks!