# Psycopg2 - Insert large data leads to server closed unexpectedly

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I've tried to see other similar problems, but they did not quite give me the answer I was looking for. My main goal is to store a large dataset into a google cloud. I tried to store around 1000 insert statement to google cloud and it went well.

In the other hand, storing over 200.000 insert statement proved to be challenge than I thought. In my code, I have this function:

```
def insert_to_gcloud(information):
    db = psycopg2.connect(database="database",
                          user="user",
                          password="password",
                          host="host",
                          port=1234)
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("".join(information))

    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

I use batch insert (suppose to be faster) where the first index contain the insert statement and the rest values. Then I use "".join() to make it into a string. To make a simple example:

> INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

```
["INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES",
"(1,2,3)," ,
"(4,5,6)," ,
"(7,8,9);" ]
```

At first, I tried to execute 200.000 insert statement, but I got an error about EOF after about 1 min. I guess it was to big to send, so I made a chunk function. Basically, it divides the array into proper size as I want it. ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks))

Then used a simple for-loop to store each one block at a time:

```
for i in range(len(chunk_block)):
    insert_to_gcloudd(chunk_block[i])
```

It seems like it was working, but I let it run over the night, used 237 min, I got this message:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
>           This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>           before or while processing the request.

My next test is to store the chunk block into files, read and log the files. If the server gets closed unexpectedly again, I can check the log. Thought, this is not a good way to do it in my opinion, but I'm out of ideas here.

So to my question, is there any option I could try? Maybe there are other tools I can use?

Comment: try `COPY` into an unindexed temp table then an insert join on the table of interest. see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559300/copy-command-with-psycopg2-library