# Adding data using postgresql commands with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, subprocess

I have a CSV file and I want to add data to my table that I created in postgresql with python, but I want to do this with the "\copy" command, not with INSERT.

```
import os
import subprocess
import psycopg2

db_name = 'postgres'
db_host = 'localhost'
db_user = 'postgres'
db_password = '123'

conn = psycopg2.connect("host= localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=123")
cur = conn.cursor()

cmd = "\copy public.table from 'C:/abc/abc.csv' csv header; | psql -U postgres".format(db_user,db_name,db_host)

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

[In short, I want to patch this process that I did on the console in python.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL8dL.png)

Comment: It looks like you are creating a connection to your database, then you are constructing your command line and pass it to shell not the connection you just created. Maybe this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24150855/2681662

Comment: From the `psycopg2` docs [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) and for your particular use [copy_from](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from).